# Segmentation fault at different places

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a pretty  decent sized program (~1000 loc) .

When i run the program ,

```
./indexer
```

Gives segmentation fault on 800th iteration .

But when i do

```
gdb indexer
run
```

It goes well beyond 800th and shows seg fault at around 1200th iteration .

I dont understand why it is happening like this . Any pointers to possible mistake I am doing ?

**EDIT:**
The question is what might be reason for different behaviour of executable under the two conditions ?

Comment: There are so many things you could be doing wrong that would result in segfault. Track the error to a specific line or function and post some code.

Comment: Don't worry about the iteration, check what is the variable that gets that segmentation fault. And then focus on it (and how it get it's value), and check how it could cause that.

Comment: the q is not about seg fault -- its about why it comes at different times when run directly / when using gdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions under which your program runs can be very different when run with the debugger and without. If you have a bug in your program, especially a bug that is *undefined behaviour*, then anything could happen.

Since the problem still happens when using the debugger, I would debug that first, and then if the problem is solved when *not* running under the debugger, you're done. Otherwise you'll have a bit more work to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on an Unix-like system, like Ubuntu, install valgrind with:

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

and run it to detect memory-related errors:

```
valgrind indexer
```

if you are on some other OS, go to the [valgrind website](http://valgrind.org/) and get install directions.

At 1k loc, I also recommend that you get in the habit of unit-testing with something like [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/): it will save you a lot of debugging time as your program gets larger.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading or writing to a memory location which has not been allocated by your program. To find out exactly what is going on here however you'll need to post the code, preferably a small example that still segfaults.